# Does there exist a primitive pythagorean triple $(a, b, c)$ with $a$ and $b$ are perfect powers (bigger than one)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

I am not able to find any such triple, only find infinitely many triples with one of it is a perfect power.

Comment: The [Beal conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal_conjecture) would rule this out.  Not sure if the special case you want is known or not.

Comment: Please use the body of your Question to give a self-contained problem statement, not (as here) a brief comment that relies on the title alone for the substance of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

A multiple of 3,4,5 gives: 27,36,45.

That is, $(3^3)^2+(6^2)^2=45^2$.

In some generality, if you have a Pythagorean triple $(a,b,c)$ where $b=d^\ell$, then $(a^{\ell+1}, (ad)^\ell, c\cdot a^\ell)$ seems to be a triple of the form you want.